# If I have to accept new terms, where I can read them up?

Tags: google-play-store, whatsapp-messenger, privacy

My favorite example for this is whatsapp.

Somewhat around May 2014 I got notified that terms had been changed and that I have to accept them and update whatsapp.

Since this was just some days after facebook bought whatsapp I tried to read these terms I had to accept.

But there was no link in the message or any info about where to read them up.

So I used the links in the playstore refering to the terms of use, which linked to:

https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/

The funny thing is, even today (March 17th, 2016) the bottom line still states:

> Date Last Modified:
>
> This Privacy Notice was last modified July 7th, 2012

So in the playstore of whats app it isn't even linking to a changed version. but since 1 billion people accepted the change of terms, I'm curious am I the only one of 1billion users who would like to know what he has accepted?

Or am I the only one who is just to stupid to find the changed version everyone else accepted?

---

A little update on my request to the support.

After sending the mail about 1 week ago, I got now an answer in which I get explained that the issues I'm experiencing are caused by my device since it isn't supported and I should consider switching to an supported device.

So it looks like they are ignoring my request about it totally...
even for an automated answer its rude to let me wait a week. any ideas where else to take the request?
They actually answered me that "the issues I'm experiencing" are due to my not supported device.

Comment: When I try to launch WhatsApp the first time after a complete uninstall of it, I see that it expects me to agree to the terms of service. When I open the terms of service, it launches my default browser and directs it to the URL https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/. So whether believe on it or not, that agreement is what the new users still agrees for and you would also have agreed for it.

Comment: So when they anounced in 2014 that they did change whatsapp terms of use, they just didn't?

Comment: Perhaps contact them and verify that they really didn't forget to update timestamp on that document? Really, it is possible that they forgot to update since I don't find that timestamp automatically included by system there.

Comment: @Firelord: I'll ask them and laugh the hell out of em if they really did and I'm the only one who noticed '^.^

Comment: @Zaibis I wouldn't be surprised you were the only one. Usually, the group of people using WA (or FB for that, or even Paypal) and the group of people reading TOS are pretty much distinct (almost no overlap). I'm in the latter group; one day I thought about using Paypal and gave up on it after an hour (!) of trying to read their TOS (when I was referred to document #5, already having open 4 documents and always being referred at about 5%). They don't want you *reading* that, or they'd present you a decent summary (which would be in the lines of: "we own you & your data, paragraph.").

Answer (score 0):

For the case of Whatsapp, I can say today, that they simply made it not easy accessible to read up their terms of service. They had as stated in OP not updated the terms of service for more than 4 years while not making them publicly available. The linked side got updated once last year. But still Whatsapp expects you to accept their "recent changes in terms of service", leaving you without any clue where they are published.

Lets see if they will maintain it now or that source will be outdated soonish again.